# First usage of PEG (Poly ethylene glycol) on surfaces against biofouling

Tags: polymers

Is there something like a "famous initial case" when people used Poly Ethylene Glycol (Poly Ethylene Oxide, PEG) as passivating layer or so on surfaces? Especially against nonspecific Protein or Peptide binding?

I found one publication from 1971: "Treatment of controlled pore glass with poly(ethylene oxide) to prevent adsorption of rabies virus" (Hiatt et al), however this has been cited only very rarely.

On the other hand there is the famous precipitation method described by Polson et al from 1964.